# change color of transparent pixel in java

Tags: java, image-processing

Now i am able to apply pixel of another image to source image pixel of pg to m. but problem is that i m loosing gradient or fading effect.

```
     public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\m.png"));
            BufferedImage patt = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\pg.png"));

            int f = 0;
            int t = 0;
            int n = 0;
            BufferedImage bff = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y) {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x) {
                    int argb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                    int nrg = patt.getRGB(x, y);

                    if(((argb>>24) & 0xff) == 0) {
                                bff.setRGB(x, y, (255<<24));
                    } else {
                                bff.setRGB(x, y, nrg);
                    }                               
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Trans : " + t + " Normal : " + n);
            File outputfile = new File("c://imagetest.png");
            ImageIO.write(bff, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }

}
```

thanks.

Comment: dont change the color...change the transperancy

Comment: how to change transperancy

Answer (score 3):

`0xff000000` is opaque black, `0x00000000` is completely transparent.

What is `0` (the colour you chose)?

Yes, it's transparent.

Try `0xff000000` or even better: `argb ^ 0xff000000`, which just changes the transparency, instead.

```
                if(((argb>>24) & 0xff) == 0) {
                            bff.setRGB(x, y, argb ^ 0xff000000);
                } else {
                            bff.setRGB(x, y, argb);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

For `BufferedImage.setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb)` the `rgb` value is made up as follows:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
Alpha    Red      Green    Blue
```

In your code you test the following:

```
if (((argb >> 24) & 0xff) == 0)
```

which tests for an Alpha value of 0, thus completely transparent.

When you find it to be true, you then set the rgb value to 0 with

```
bff.setRGB(x, y, 0);
```

So you are setting it to transparent again.

Change that to

```
bff.setRGB(x, y, (255<<24));
```

or

```
bff.setRGB(x, y, 0xff000000); //This should be better
```

which will change it to an opaque black pixel. This will have a binary value of

> 11111111000000000000000000000000

***Edit:*** [Moritz Petersen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21136224/3168251) should work better as it retains the pixel's colour while removing transparency.

If you would like to set it to a specific colour you could do:

```
bff.setRGB(x, y, 0xffff0000); // red
bff.setRGB(x, y, 0xff00ff00); // green
bff.setRGB(x, y, 0xff0000ff); // blue
```

or any combination of red, green and blue values.

Comment: if i want to add pixel of another image to this image that are non-transparent.

Comment: `bff.setRGB(x, y, argb ^ 0xff000000);` (from Moritz Petersen) Will achieve that. The reason why you are now getting it all white is that the original image set the pixels to transparent white.

Comment: i have edited my problem, now when i apply pixel of different image to source image, i m loosing fading and gradient effects.

Comment: when i use (nrg+argb) adding the pixel of both, then somewhere i am achieving what i need, but only problem with black pixels, all black pixels are now white.