# how to restrict the mouse just on the icon on java

Tags: java, icons, jbutton, mouse

I have button on frame. On that button I put an image, which as you see that is a search icon. I remove the visible border on the button. But still I have two questions:

1. when I put the mouse on the button, the image and also the invisible button border is clickable, what I need is restrict it just on the icon.
2. I want to make the icon focusable by clicking like click on the simple button.

Search Icon:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mRBj.png]

Answer (score 0):

What sort of image file format are you using?   If it's a format with transparency support, you'll have to implement an algorithm that checks whether the click coordinate is inside of the non-transparent pixels of the icon you're using.  You'll have to offset the rgb checks on the image pixels by the position of the image on your frame as well.  Use this as a reference - [Java Image Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136056/change-color-of-transparent-pixel-in-java)